# getelementsbyname Return Undefined value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm a javascript newbie and I have try this.

```html
<html>
<style>
#WoodNumInput {
 width:40px;
}
</style>
<body>
<script>
var i;
var woodtypeAB = ["AB_W15_L100","AB_W20_L100", "AB_W25_L100", "AB_W30_L100"];

 for (i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
  document.write("<div id = 'box'><input type ='number' name = '" + woodtypeAB[i] + "' id = 'WoodNumInput' value = " + i + "></div><br/>"); 
  }
</script>
<br/>
<input type = "button" value = "calculate" onclick= "Calculation()">
<div id = "Test"></div>
<script> 
 function Calculation() {
 var ShowResult = document.getElementsByName("woodtypeAB[3]").value;
 document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = ShowResult;
 }
</script>
</body>
```

The value returns undefined and I still can't figure it out.

Thank in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be, the sum of all the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong.

First, you're trying to get the `.value` from a collection instead of from individual elements.

Also, the elements you're creating have a name value of `AB_...` but you're trying to fetch using a very different name.

I think you perhaps thought that the `woodtypeAB[3]` you're fetching would somehow translate to the variable and index you used to create the element's name. That's not how it works.

When you created the element, the concatenation did *not* add `woodtypeAB[3]` as the name, but rather the ***value*** located at that index of that array. So to fetch that particular name, you'd use its array value of `AB_W30_L100`.

```html
<html>
<style>
  #WoodNumInput {
    width: 40px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="Calculation()">
  <div id="Test"></div>
  <br>
  <script>
    var i;
    var woodtypeAB = ["AB_W15_L100", "AB_W20_L100", "AB_W25_L100", "AB_W30_L100"];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      document.write("<div id = 'box'><input type ='number' name = '" + woodtypeAB[i] + "' id = 'WoodNumInput' value = " + i + "></div><br/>");
    }
  </script>
  <br/>
  <script>
    function Calculation() {
      var ShowResult = document.getElementsByName("AB_W30_L100");
      if (ShowResult.length != 0) {
        document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML = ShowResult[0].value;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Although something tells me that you actually are going to want to select all those input elements and perform some calculation on them. That'll require additional tweaks to your code.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
var ShowResult = document.getElementsByName("woodtypeAB[3]").value
```

should be

```
var ShowResult = document.getElementsByName(woodtypeAB[3])[0].value
```

Since `"woodtypeAB[3]"` is surrounded by quotation marks it will be interpreted as a string rather than the actual array value.

`document.getElementsByName()` returns a NodeList of elements so you will have to explicitly say that you want the first item in the NodeList, hence `[0]`